# What does cpp, jni, jniLibs directories, and android.mk and CMake.txt do in Android

Tags: android, c++, cmake, java-native-interface

When configuring a project to add **C** and **C++** in an **Android** project a few things come up in a project's directory tree.

There's the `cpp`, `jniLibs`, and the `jni` directories.

There are also `android.mk` and `CMakeLists.txt` files.

1. What are the purposes \ what should be included in the `cpp`, `jniLibs`, and the `jni` directories?
2. Do `android.mk` and `CMakeLists.txt` work interchangeably?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. `cpp` is a directory where you put your `cpp` code.

   `jniLibs` is an optional directory, can be added if you need to include some external `libs` (.so files).

   [CMakeLists.txt](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake) is a configuration file for [CMake](https://cmake.org/), which is a build tool for `c++` code.

   [android.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk) is a configuration file used to build cpp code, similar to [GNU makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). No longer used now, replaced by `CMake` tool. You should use `CMake` now instead of `android.mk`, but you can still used if you want.
2. `CMakeLists.txt` is a replacement of the old way `android.mk`